# How to programmatically build a jobs in a view in hudson

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-api

I have a 500+ Jenkins jobs in a particular view. I need to trigger those jobs programmatically using the Jenkins script console. I tried with the below code but it didn't work.

```
    import hudson.model.*;
    triggerbuild{
      def job = hudson.instance.getview("xxxx").listItem("Job")
      hudson.instance.build("job")
}
```

Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the bare minimal solution I can come up with, assuming you don't have any parameters to pass and you don't really care about the build cause, etc.

```
def jen = Jenkins.instance;
def viewName = 'TECHNICAL'

def jobs = jen.getView(viewName).getJobNames()
jobs.each { job -> 
   println "Running Job: " + job
   jen.getQueue().schedule(jen.getJob(job), 0, null, null)
}
```

Build on top of this as required. Probably you may have to identify different types of Jobs and execute them accordingly.